# CSS Drop-menu not working in IE 7

Tags: css, internet-explorer-7, drop-down-menu

Here is the sample site:

http://tronitech.brettatkin.com/solutions.asp

In IE 7, the drop-downs aren't working correctly (really not at all).  The do show on hover but that is about it.

This is my first attempt at working through creating CSS only drop-menus, so I'm welcome to all feedback and criticism about the code in general.

Thanks

Brett

Comment: Here is my CSS file: http://tronitech.brettatkin.com/inc/styles.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A fix is very easy:

On line 266 of `styles.css`:

```
#nav ul li {
    float: left;
    position: relative;
}
```

change: `#nav ul li` to `#nav > ul > li`. Problem fixed.

That is, replace the [descendant combinators](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/descendantselector) (a space: ) with direct [child combinators](http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/childselector) (`>`). This prevents the `li`s inside the submenus from having the problematic `float: left`, while still allowing the starting `li`s to keep `float: left`.

Comment: Yes, it fixed it!!  What does that mean though?

Comment: I just added an explanation to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You have set `float: left;` in this css `#nav ul li` which is affecting sub lists as well.

You need to add `float:none;` in the css `#nav ul li:hover ul li`

or

do the change: `#nav ul li` to `#nav > ul > li` as thirtydot mentioned in his answer.

Comment: Your fix also works, and is also very simple. Though, it seems to work better with `#nav ul li ul li { float:none }` *(remove the `:hover`)*

Comment: Won't removing the :hover cause the menu's not to load?

Answer (score 0):

Solving issues like this generally requires that the CSS and accompanying code - if JS is used to add a class, for example - be posted along with your question. I'd guess that there's an issue with sizing (margin, padding, or height change) in the menu, to begin with. Looks like when hovering over the first sub-menu item, the remaining <li> items get bumped. The float looks obvious, and since the second item jumps right, that would be my guess. I'm not seeing any class changes, so does your CSS rely strictly on hover?

Comment: Yes, CSS is hover only.  I don't understand the "float looks obvious" statement.